# Seperate SSRS report weekly between a date range

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently have to run a report weekly back to 2014 till now. Is there a way where I can provide it a date range of 4 months and the report can be divided by calendar weeks within the date range?

Any questions, feel free to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a [data-driven subscription](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/data-driven-subscription-in-ssrs-2008-r2.html) on the report.

Build a query that returns a table with one row per each set of parameter values you want to run.  Assign the columns to the correct parameter and then run the subscription.

If you have specified a file share as the output, all the different versions of the report will output to that share.

Obviously this requires you to provide SSRS access to that file share.